# Oracle OBIEE 12c: find outliers

Tags: oracle, obiee, outliers

I created a table like this in OBIEE 12c:

[image]

Now I want to color in red the values that are 2 standard deviation above the mean.

I want to do that for each value per row (e.g. A, a1, a1.1).

Thanks in advance for your help,
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for column properties - conditional format - add condition - colour it red.

[image]

Comment: Yes Max, that is my aim. But I am not able to calcualte standtard deviation from the function STDDEV in OBIEE. I mean, using the values of "Amount" per "Day" I am not able to add at the end of my table a variable that contein the value of standard deviation of "amount" by "Area", "Category", "Subcategory" as a function of "Day". Then I will take each standard deviation in order to color in red value above of it.